# Extracting conditional numeric values from character data in R

Tags: percentage, information-extraction, sorting

Stuck on a data tidying problem, and not sure how to work around it. I have messy character data on whisky, which I'm looking to organise so that I can conduct some analyses. Specifically, I'm looking to extract the abv % values from the product name, and place them into a new column. An example of the current data would look like this:

| Name | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Aberfeldy, 12 year old, 40% | 40 |
| Ardbeg, 1974 Vintage, Cask #3524, 49.9% | 20000 |

Whilst what I would like the data to look like this:

| Name | Price | ABV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aberfeldy, 12 year old, 40% | 40 | 40 |
| Ardbeg, 1974 Vintage, Cask #3524, 49.9% | 20000 | 49 |

I have so little experience with messy data of this sort, so I have no idea what needs to be done. I have tried experimenting with `gsub`, and I'm getting frustratingly close! (I can extract the 40% value from the Aberfeldy, but can only extract the 9 from the 49.9% of the Ardbeg).

```
#demo
  name <- c("Aberfeldy, 12 year old, 40%", "Ardbeg, 1974 Vintage, Cask #3524, 49.9%")
  price <- c(40, 20000)
example_data <- data.frame(name, price)

attempt <- as.numeric(gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*%", "\\1", example_data$name))

# Attemp results
40  9
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: This question is **not** on topic here (more a stack overflow question). But try this: `gsub(".*?(\\d+\\.?\\d*)%.*", "\\1", example_data$name)`. The capturing group matches one or more digits following an optional decimal point and zero or more digits prior to the literal % sign (and potentially other characters).

Comment: Thank you so much @Stefan! That worked. And thanks to whomever moved it to Stack Overflow! I lapsed in concentration when logging the question.